# How to know if I can trust an SPFX webpart?

Tags: permissions, spfx, security, api, graph

I am in the process of implementing an spfx webpart but before I need to make sure it is not a security threat.

From researching I was not able to find if there is any way to run a check or provide a validation that the webpart is safe for the organization as it does ask for Graph API permissions, I do not think there is any issues with it, but I need to be able to have cleareance.

This is the webpart: https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-accordion-dynamic-section

Comment: it sounds like this directive is coming from your organization. Does your org have a standard code analysis process?